# Grub questions, image background, version and Grub Customizer program

Tags: 12.04

Ubuntu 12.04

First of what exactly is my Grub version?  Do I have Grub2?
my grub -v command says :

1.99-21ubuntu3.9

and when I tried to update it said I had most recent.

Anyway I want to change the background image of my grub screen, I've tried EVERYTHING, it's in the folder, I've tried Grub Customizer, nothing works.

The image is in the right dimensions is it the file size?  It's like 400kb...

anyone have experience with this program?

Answer (score 0):

Grub customizer can set a custom background image for your grub loader screen but remember that you need to do some color restriction opearations and image should be stored in .PNG format then only it will be placed as a background of grub screen.